# SQL Server create ordered #Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to create ordered #Temp table:

```
WITH Ordered AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Quality] DESC) AS RowNumber, ImageID, Quality, Border, IsBest
  FROM [CatalogImages].[dbo].[Images] ORDER BY Quality)

SELECT *
  INTO #Temp
  FROM Ordered ;

 SELECT * FROM #Temp ;
```

but I get error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 82
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid
>   in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common
>   table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

How to create ordered temp table?

Comment: Google the message. This is a well-known error.

Comment: Oh, thanks, i was found solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985921/sql-error-with-order-by-in-subquery

Comment: As a side-note: you cannot have an **ordered** table - temporary or not. When you select from a table in SQL, unless you **explicitly specify** an `ORDER BY` - there **is no guaranteed order**

Answer (score 1):

The Error is because you're trying to do an Order By inside a Common Table Expression, which is not allowed.

Just from what you've posted, it does not appear that your CTE is required.  You could just do this :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Quality] DESC) AS RowNumber, ImageID, Quality, Border, IsBest 
INTO #Temp 
ORDER BY Quality; 

SELECT * 
FROM #Temp 
ORDER BY Quality;
```

(which doesn't suggest that a temp table is required, either...)