# How can I use ORDER BY in a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My query is:

```
SET @query=
  N'SELECT TaskID
    ,Company
    ,TaskSource
    ,Urgency
    ,Activity
    ,StatusName
    ,RequesterMailID
    ,tsk.CreatedDate
    ,tsk.LastUpdatedDate
    ,LastUpdatedBy
    ,(DATEDIFF(DAY, dbo.GetTimeByTimeZoneId(SLAStartTime, '' NZST ''), dbo.GetTimeByTimeZoneId(SLAActualEndTime, '' NZST ''))) 
        + 1 
        - count([Pact_OEMS].[dbo].[MstHolidays](HolidayDate)) AS AgeinDaystilldate
FROM TaskMaster tsk
LEFT OUTER JOIN TrnTaskReportDetails tsr ON tsk.TaskID = tsr.intTaskId
FULL OUTER JOIN TrnSLADetails sla ON tsk.TaskID = sla.intTaskId
FULL OUTER JOIN [Pact_OEMS].[dbo].[MstHolidays] ON [Pact_OEMS].[dbo].[MstHolidays].HolidayId = sla.intTaskId
WHERE CreatedDate >= @FromDate
    AND CreatedDate <= @ToDate
    AND TaskID = @TaskID
ORDER BY tsk.CreatedDate
    ,tsk.LastUpdatedDate'
```

And the error:

> The `ORDER BY` clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables,
>   subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

How can I use `ORDER BY` in a sub query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031421/the-order-by-clause-is-invalid-in-views-inline-functions-derived-tables-subqu)

Comment: Does that specific statement in fact produce that error? There's no view, inline function, derived table, subquery or cte in play here as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Try using window function like below

```
    SELECT TaskID,
       Company,
       TaskSource,
       Urgency,
       Activity,
       StatusName,
       RequesterMailID,
       tsk.CreatedDate,
       tsk.LastUpdatedDate,
       LastUpdatedBy,
       (DATEDIFF(DAY, dbo.GetTimeByTimeZoneId(SLAStartTime, '' NZST ''), dbo.GetTimeByTimeZoneId(SLAActualEndTime, '' NZST '')))+1-COUNT([Pact_OEMS].[dbo].[MstHolidays](HolidayDate)) AS AgeinDaystilldate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TaskID ORDER BY tsk.CreatedDate,
                                                      tsk.LastUpdatedDate) rNO
FROM TaskMaster tsk
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TrnTaskReportDetails tsr ON tsk.TaskID = tsr.intTaskId
     FULL OUTER JOIN TrnSLADetails sla ON tsk.TaskID = sla.intTaskId
     FULL OUTER JOIN [Pact_OEMS].[dbo].[MstHolidays] ON [Pact_OEMS].[dbo].[MstHolidays].HolidayId = sla.intTaskId
WHERE CreatedDate >= @FromDate
      AND CreatedDate <= @ToDate
      AND TaskID = @TaskID
```

I would also recommend to read this [article](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-window-functions/) as it will help you align your thoughts and approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How should i give group by clause ?

Comment: You want to group by which columns?