# Error when adding order by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Goodday, Please check my query first.

```
SELECT *
FROM
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT row, a.tanggal, b.OutletCode, c.Nilai, a.Nip, b.Fullname,
        a.KodePenilaian, f.Description AS posisilama, d.ShortDesc AS posisibaru
    FROM penilaian_header a 
    LEFT JOIN Employee b
        ON a.Nip = b.Nip 
    LEFT JOIN Position f
        ON b.PositionCode = f.PositionCode 
    LEFT JOIN Position d
        ON a.PositionCode = d.PositionCode 
    LEFT JOIN arealeader g
        ON g.OutletCode = b.OutletCode 
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KodePenilaianH
                                  ORDER BY idPenilaiand DESC) AS Row,
            Nilai, KodePenilaianH
        FROM penilaian_Detail
    ) c
        ON a.KodePenilaian = c.KodePenilaianH 
    WHERE a.Outlet LIKE '%%' AND Periode LIKE '%%'
    ORDER BY b.OutletCode ASC
) nilai PIVOT (SUM(nilai) FOR ROW IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) piv;
```

My problem is when i'm add `Order by` my query error. Here is the error :

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
```

Without `Order By` my query working fine.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you're using `ORDER BY` in a subquery.  Maybe you can add `TOP` to the subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `ORDER BY b.OutletCode ASC` is the cause of the error, rather than the `ORDER BY` inside the partition, which is necessary and should be allowed.

If you want to return all records, you can use `TOP` with a large number, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2147483647 row, a.tanggal, b.OutletCode, c.Nilai, a.Nip,
        b.Fullname, a.KodePenilaian, f.Description AS posisilama, d.ShortDesc AS posisibaru
    FROM penilaian_header a 
    LEFT JOIN Employee b
        ON a.Nip = b.Nip 
    ...
    ORDER BY b.OutletCode ASC
) nilai PIVOT (SUM(nilai) FOR ROW IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) piv;
```

Comment: It's a great lesson for me. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985921/sql-error-with-order-by-in-subquery) for a more thorough discussion.